# How can I convert image base64 and upload it using url from server to the project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, base64

I have some dynamic images from server and I want to show them in a mobile app with using their url. images appear in android app but in ios app disappear(I used jqueryMobile in the project and phonegap for adding to ios and android). I had some search about this topic and I find a solution; I have to convert images to base64 mode and upload them the project. if you have any different idea about this problem please share with me, if not, how can I convert images base64 and upload them to the project using JS?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the apache library org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 class.
It has a method call encodeBase64 which should help in your case.